# What does the ^ scanf modifier actually do?

Tags: c, scanf

I have searched and read that the ^ modifier states to ignore whatever you put inside of the [ ] in `scanf`. For example:

```
int val;   
scanf("%[^abc] %d, &val);  
printf("val is %d", val);
```

Now, if I input abc42, I thought the abc would be ignored and 42 would get stored into val. But, this doesn't happen.

I also tried to suppress the `scanf` by making it:

```
scanf("%*[^abc] %d, &val);
```

but this did not work either. So I am confused on what ^ actually does.

Comment: Your code sample has mismatched quotes. Please post exactly the code you are trying

Answer (score 6):

When you say you want `scanf` to ignore certain characters, I think you mean you want `scanf` to read those characters and then ignore them. In order to do that, you use the `%*[]` format specifier:

```
scanf("%*[abc] %d", &val);
```

The `[abc]` tells `scanf` to read any number of the characters between the brackets (i.e. a, b, or c). The `*` tells `scanf` to ignore those characters, then the `%d` reads the value into `val`.

The `^` specifier tells `scanf` to read any number of characters *other* than those in between the brackets, which is the opposite of what you want to do, I think.

Comment: If you delete the space in the scanf, it fails. Why is this?

Answer (score 5):

You need to carefully **read the documentation of [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)** and to enable all warnings when compiling (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...); you'll probably have been warned with such a compilation. You should also use the result of `scanf` and run your program in a debugger (`gdb`)

```
scanf("%[^abc] %d", &val);
```

is reading two items, the first being a string of characters outside of the set {`a`,`b`,`c`} (and the second being an integer going "nowhere").

So your program has [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (UB) because you call `scanf` with one argument less than it should, and because the first argument should be the location of a wide enough `char` buffer. UB can be really [bad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108), so you need to *always avoid it*.

You might try:

```
int val= 0;
char buf[32]; // 30+1 could be enough....
memset (buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
if (scanf("%30[^abc] %d", buf, &val) == 2) {
  printf("got string %s and int %d\n", buf, val);
}
else { // handle scanf failure 
}
```

Comment: Minor: Unclear why a difference of 2 in 32, 30 with `char buf[32]; ... scanf("%30[^abc] %d", ...`.  Expected 1.

Answer (score 2):

It gives the following warning message when I am compiling the code.

test.c:5:2: warning: format ‘%[^abc’ expects argument of type ‘char *’,but  argument 2 has type 'int *’ [-Wformat]
test.c:5:2: warning: format ‘%d’ expects a matching ‘int *’ argument [-Wformat]

You have to pass the character array to the scanf function, when you are using this.

So, modify the scanf line to bellow, and check what happens.

```
char buf[100];
int val;
scanf("%[^[abc] %d",buf,&val);
```

The %[^abc] it reads the string, if any character in the bracket other than the ^ is occurs it will fill the address of the character array with the reading characters.
So, this is used only when we are reading the string input.

Comment: Really want 2 `[` in `"%[^[abc] %d"` ?

Comment: you can use backslash in before of the bracket, like scanf("%[^\[abc]",buf);

Comment: There is no backslash in your comment's example `"%[^[abc]"`.

Comment: oh. Sorry. I forget to put that. "%[^\\[abc]"

Comment: `\[` is not a defined escape sequence in C.  So`"%[^\[abc]"` is a problem.  It is unclear why this answer suggests using `"%[^[abc]` rather than `"%[^abc]`.